# Neither Chrome nor Chromium launches after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, google-chrome, chromium

I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 a few days ago, neither Chrome nor Chromium launches after that (there were no errors/problems in installation of both). Here's the result of executing two commands for running each application:

`chromium-browser`

```
Using PPAPI flash.
[4725:4763:0814/235026:ERROR:nss_util.cc(740)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/ali/.pki/nssdb): libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[4725:4763:0814/235026:ERROR:nss_util.cc(211)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[4725:4763:0814/235026:FATAL:nss_util.cc(213)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
#0 0x7ff6474a3dee base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7ff6474c242e logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x7ff64375c066 <unknown>
#3 0x7ff64375c3b0 crypto::EnsureNSSInit()
#4 0x7ff6513dcb95 net::CertDatabase::GetInstance()
#5 0x7ff651494ace net::MultiThreadedCertVerifier::MultiThreadedCertVerifier()
#6 0x55d1e722e8d3 <unknown>
#7 0x7ff64ef14f3e content::BrowserThreadImpl::Init()
#8 0x7ff64ef1445f content::BrowserProcessSubThread::Init()
#9 0x7ff647506abd base::Thread::ThreadMain()
#10 0x7ff647502050 <unknown>
#11 0x7ff63bf176fa start_thread
#12 0x7ff63bc4db5d clone

Aborted (core dumped)
```

`google-chrome`

```
[4778:4811:0814/235057:ERROR:nss_util.cc(744)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/ali/.pki/nssdb): libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[4778:4811:0814/235057:ERROR:nss_util.cc(212)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[4778:4811:0814/235057:FATAL:nss_util.cc(214)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by:

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Based on the transcript you provided, the `libnss3` dynamic library cannot be found. The following should resolve the issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

Comment: libnss3 is already the newest version (2:3.23-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)!

Comment: @AliKhoshsafa ok, but it might not be linked properly as you get `libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and the file is a part of this package. Maybe you can try to reinstall...

Comment: I removed and installed many times both from terminal and software center, but nothing changed!