# How can I get rid of the Aw snap error in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Suddenly I keep getting the **Aw snap!** error in Chrome and I can't get rid of it, I've tried to `rm -rf .config/google-chrome/` but that didn't help... any suggestions?

I'm using

`$ google-chrome --version Google Chrome 39.0.2171.71`

and launching it from the shell gives me this:

```
$ google-chrome&
[1] 12762
ron@regDesktopHome:~$ [9:9:0531/192000:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[9:9:0531/192000:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[11:11:0531/192000:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[11:11:0531/192000:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[13:13:0531/192003:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[13:13:0531/192003:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[15:15:0531/192006:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[15:15:0531/192006:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[17:17:0531/192009:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[17:17:0531/192009:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
```

Comment: Why are you using v39? Google Chrome is currently at v58. And is your computer/OS 32-bit or 64-bit? And see if https://askubuntu.com/questions/812837/neither-chrome-nor-chromium-launches-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04 helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove current chrome version with this commands

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After try install again with this commands.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Finally try to open with terminal.

```
google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Remove new version of Chrome

   1. Go to Desktop and right click on the Chrome icon
   2. Select open file location and find the numbered file
   3. Delete high numbered file (The new update file)
   4. Then reopen Chrome
2. Clear browsing history and catches

   **Browser settings > Advanced settings > Privacy > Clear browsing data**
3. Run a full virus scan and remove all viruses (Virus will destroy Chrome activities)
4. Turn off Anti-virus real time virus scan for a moment and try Chrome (Some time anti-virus block some codes and applications)

Comment: Viruses? In Ubuntu? Really?

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 Make sure your computer's connected to Wi-Fi or a wired network

Step 2 Clear your cache of chrome

step 3 Clear your cache and cookies

Step 4: Close other tabs, extensions, & apps

Still Not Working Then Restart Computer