# Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. Error code: SIGSEGV

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, browser

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, and I got this message while I am trying to post a picture on Facebook by using google chrome:

```
Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. Error code: SIGSEGV
```

Even though I reinstalled google chrome as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920930/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-aw-snap-error-in-chrome).
Are there any recommendations to solve this issue?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try to post the same picture on Facebook in Firefox?

Comment: @karel No, it doesn't. The issue with google chrome only.

Comment: Maybe some inactive process is hanging in Chrome. Close Chrome and kill all the Chrome processes in the built-in System Monitor application. If that doesn't work log out and log back in.

Comment: @karel I killed all chrome processes and log out and then log in back again, but the issue still resides ):

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this a couple of times.  Go to the Chrome browser menu (three dots on the upper right side of the address bar on mine), select

- Settings
- Advanced
- System
- Turn off "Use hardware acceleration when available"
- Restart Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't occur in Firefox, and it isn't solved by logging out and logging back in again. It could be caused by one of the extensions that is installed in Chrome.  Disable your Chrome extensions one by one until you isolate the extension that is causing the problem, and then re-enable all of the other installed Chrome extensions except for that one.

If that doesn't work try signing out of Facebook in Chrome, and then sign back in again with your Facebook password.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not work. I disabled all of the extensions I installed, but the problem is still resides ):

Comment: Have you done anything experimental with your `chrome://flags` ? That's a longshot, so I mentioned it last.

Comment: No, I haven't. I simply installed it from the above-attached link.

Comment: I signed out and sign in back to my Facebook account, but the issue was not solved :(